# How to manipulate a html list with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have unsorted list in html. Some `li`'s have a `class="checked"`. 
If the `li` element have the `class='checked'` it should hide me the span inside the `li` element.

My example:

```js
$('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') == 'checked'){
        $('li span').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
    <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
    <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
    <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But my code is hidding every list element. Why is that so ?

Comment: try using $(this).find('li span').hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more effective to do that this way:

```
$('ul li.checked span').hide();
```

Also, consider using plain CSS:

```
ul li.checked span {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I didn't consider the CSS. This is a nice solution !

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)`

```js
 $('ul li').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'checked'){
          $(this).find('span').hide(); // If want to hide only span
          //$(this).hide(); // if want to hide li
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
    <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
    <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
    <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$('li span')` would select all elements instead select span within the current element.

```
$('span', this).hide();
// or
$(this).find('span').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
    <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
    <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
    <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>
<script>
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'checked'){
            $('span',this).hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also, it's better to use [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method to check element has a certain class since the element may have multiple class.

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
        $('span', this).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
  <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
  <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
  <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>
<script>
  $('ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
      $('span', this).hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

---

There is no necessary for the [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each) method in your code, you can reduce into a single line by updating selector with the class.

```
$('ul li.checked span').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
  <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
  <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
  <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>
<script>
  $('ul li.checked span').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul li.checked span').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
  <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
  <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
  <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

1. No need for iteration just find the li with class checked then find span then hide

Answer (score 0):

you are hiding all spans with your selector. Find span in the current element you interact with

```js
$('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).find('span').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="checked" id="item-1"><span class='priorityValue'>1</span></li>
    <li class="checked" id="item-2"><span class='priorityValue'>2</span></li>
    <li id="item-3"><span class='priorityValue'>3</span></li>
    <li id="item-4"><span class='priorityValue'>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**: due to Mohammad comment I suggest to check it the element has a checked class, not check the whole class attribue

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.checked span').hide();
```

You can use above code , each function is not needed for this function